# Writing Fibonacci sequence in Java starting from certain term

Tags: java

I am trying to write a Fibonacci sequence generator based on Java. I saw many examples on the Internet for instance:

```
public class Fibonacci {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        generateFibonacci(20);  // generate the first 20 fibonacci numbers
    }

    public static void generateFibonacci(long limit) {
        long first = 0;
        long second = 1;
        System.out.print(first+", "+second);
        for(long i=1;i<limit;i++) {
            long next = first + second;
            System.out.print(", "+next);
            first = second;
            second = next;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

And it works fine. The problem is that not only I want to generate the first 20 numbers, but I also need to specify a starting point. For example:

```
public List<Long> generateFibonacci(long startFrom, long numberTerms) {

}
```

Doing:

```
generateFibonacci(5, 10);
```

Should output:
8l
13l 
21l 
34l 
55l 
89l 
144l
233l
377l

I have tried the following code but it doesnt seem to be performing the desired action:

```
public class example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        generateFibonacci(10, 5); 
    }

    public static void generateFibonacci(long limit, long startPoint) {
        long first = 0;
        long second = 1;
        long endPoint = startPoint + limit;
        System.out.print(first + ", " + second);
        for (long i = 1; i < endPoint; i++) {
            long next = first + second;
            if (i > startPoint) {
                System.out.print(", " + next);
            }
            ;
            System.out.print(", " + next);
            first = second;
            second = next;
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this in an efficient way?

Comment: there is one `;` too much after the if. are there some errors?

Comment: If you take two integers as your starting point (to replace your `first` and `second` variables), you can solve the problem easily, but I'm guessing you need items of the "canonical" Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: I didnt see any error with that character after the if. I have removed it but sill get: 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 13, 21, 21, 34, 34, 55, 55, 89, 89, 144, 144, 233, 233, 377, 377, 610, 610

Comment: It might be better to split your problem into two functions. Try modifying your `generateFibonacci` function to create the fibonacci sequence up to the given limit and put them into a list. Then use a second function to print out the last `x` numbers of that sequence from the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you said output must be like this

```
 8                                                                                                                                                                   
 [13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377]
```

and you want to return  a list of fibonacci numbers

you can return a list as you want in this way !

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Long> list = generateFibonacci(10, 5);
    System.out.println(list.size());     
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.toArray()));     
}

public static List<Long>  generateFibonacci(long limit, long startPoint) {
    List<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();

    long first = 0;
    long second = 1;
    long endPoint = startPoint + limit - 1;
    //System.out.print(first + ", " + second);
    if (startPoint==0){
            list.add(0);
            list.add(1);
    }else if (startPoint ==1){
            list.add(1);
    }
    for (long i = 2; i < endPoint; i++) {
        long next = first + second;
        if (i > startPoint) {
            // System.out.println(next);
            list.add(next);
        }

        first = second;
        second = next;
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: It works! But if I do: List<Long> list = generateFibonacci(9, 0); output is [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21] . So the list is not containing the first two terms of the sequence. Which are 0 and 1.

Comment: You can use if statements to fix this problem based on start point and limitation,  I put a simple if in answer but it wants more conditions to checkout limitation to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

`if (i > startPoint)` Here you do not have to put conditions on `i` but on `next`.

> The problem is that not only I want to generate the first 20 numbers,
>   but I also need to specify a starting point.

Also, I'm not sure why you are printing the first two elements i.e. `0` and `1`. I have removed the `sysout()` to meet the `startPoint` condition as you specified.

Here is the corrected code snippet:

```
public static void generateFibonacci(long limit, long startPoint) {
    long first = 0;
    long second = 1;
    long endPoint = startPoint + limit;
    long next = first + second;
    for (long i = 1; i < endPoint; i++) {
        if (next > startPoint) {
            System.out.print(next + ", ");
        }
        first = second;
        second = next;
        next = first + second;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610
```

Answer (score 0):

Line 10 is always going to print 0 and 1, so remove that.

You have a semi-colon on line 16, and line 17 prints all Fibonacci numbers which is why you get two of the ones you want

Try:

```
public class example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    generateFibonacci(10, 5); 
}

public static void generateFibonacci(long limit, long startPoint) {
    long first = 0;
    long second = 1;
    long endPoint = startPoint + limit;
    for (long i = 1; i < endPoint; i++) {
        long next = first + second;
        if (i == startPoint) {
            System.out.print(next);
        }
        else if ( i > startPoint){
            System.out.print(", " + next);
        }
        first = second;
        second = next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have to calculate the initial Fibonacci numbers anyway, just use the standard method and do this:

```
public static void generateFibonacci(long limit, long startPoint) {
    return generateFibonacci(limit).subList(startPoint - 1, limit);
}
```